# How to use closest() in a proper way in js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Student here!
Lets say i have `function append()` which generates `<li>` items inside an `<ol>`,those li items contain 2 buttons,one for removing the `<li>` that lies within and one for creating the same item but inside itself this time,in order to make another list layer.
Both by using the `closest()` method.

i cant figure out how to use the ADD `<button>`,i can call it but i cannot it make it work the way i want to.
**I get this** : [image]
**But i want to get something like this** : [image]

this is how i'm trying to do it :

```js
function append() {
var ol = document.getElementById("ol1");
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.innerHTML = (`LIST ITEM <input class=input><button class=add>ADD</button><button class=remove>REMOVE</button>`);

ol.append(li)
  
  
  document.getElementById("ol1").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("remove")) tgt.closest("li").remove();
  if (tgt.classList.contains("add")) tgt.closest("li").appendChild(li);
})
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <button id="btn1" onclick="append()">Append</button>
  <ol id="ol1">
  </ol>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you add the event as parameter (`li..addEventListener("click", append`); you can get the actual button that has been clicked by `event.target`. Then you can find the closest parent being a `li`. On this you can then create a new `ol` to which you want to add the new `li` item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To number with `1.`, `1.1`, `1.2`, `2.`, `2.1`, `3.`, you need to use *CSS*. The `counters` function, obtains the number of the `li`. Each time an `ol` appears, the counter is reset to `1.`. When a `li` appears, the top counter is used, concatenated with the new next new number of the previous `li`.

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item
}
li {
  display: block;
}
li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
  counter-increment: item;
}
```

In the `append` function, we add the `li`... For this, we call another function, which we will call `create_li()` which does the creation of the `li`.

```js
function append() {
  document.querySelector("#ol1").append( create_li() )
}
```

In the `create_li()` function, we create the `li` and return it with `return li`. In `li`, we add the two `button` elements, `add` and `remove`, but instead of doing it through a string, we do it with the function we already know, that is to say, `document.createElement()`, and also, on each button, we can add una función que llamaremos `button_click` function, used to receive the click event through `addEventListener`.

```js
function create_li(){
  var li = document.createElement("li")
  var add = document.createElement("button")
  var remove = document.createElement("button")

  li.innerHTML = "LIST ITEM <input class=input>"

  add.className = "add"
  remove.className = "remove"
  add.innerHTML = "+"
  remove.innerHTML = "-"
  add.addEventListener("click",button_click)
  remove.addEventListener("click",button_click)

  li.appendChild(add)
  li.appendChild(remove)
  
  return li
}
```

The `button_click` function, what it does is create the `ol` and `li` structure. In addition, it detects if the button clicked is the `add` or `remove`.

```js
function button_click(e) {

  const tgt = e.target;
  var litg = tgt.closest("li")
  var oltg = litg.querySelector("ol")

  if(oltg==null){
    var ol = document.createElement("ol")
    litg.appendChild(ol)
    oltg = ol
  }

  if (tgt.classList.contains("remove")){
    litg.remove()
  }
  if (tgt.classList.contains("add")){
    oltg.appendChild( create_li() )
  }
}
```

The *HTML* structure is based on the `li` has to be inside the `ol`, and each *sublist* has to have an `ol` inside the `li`.

```html
<ol>
    <li>
        1.
        <ol>
            <li>1.1</li>
            <li>1.2</li>
            <li>1.3</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
        2.
        <ol>
            <li>2.1</li>
            <li>2.2</li>
            <li>2.3</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
        3.
        <ol>
            <li>3.1</li>
            <li>3.2</li>
            <li>3.3</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Finished code:

```js
function button_click(e) {

  const tgt = e.target;
  var litg = tgt.closest("li")
  var oltg = litg.querySelector("ol")
  if(oltg==null){
    var ol = document.createElement("ol")
    litg.appendChild(ol)
    oltg = ol
  }

  if (tgt.classList.contains("remove")){
    litg.remove()
  }
  if (tgt.classList.contains("add")){
    oltg.appendChild( create_li() )
  }
}
function create_li(){
  var li = document.createElement("li")
  var add = document.createElement("button")
  var remove = document.createElement("button")

  li.innerHTML = "LIST ITEM <input class=input>"

  add.className = "add"
  remove.className = "remove"
  add.innerHTML = "+"
  remove.innerHTML = "-"
  add.addEventListener("click",button_click)
  remove.addEventListener("click",button_click)

  li.appendChild(add)
  li.appendChild(remove)
  
  return li
}

function append() {
  document.querySelector("#ol1").append( create_li() )
}
```

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item
}
li {
  display: block;
}
li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
  counter-increment: item;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn1" onclick="append()">Append</button>
<ol id="ol1"></ol>
```

Comment: Is this considered functional programming ?
Very neat and comprehensible,taught me stuff,thank you !

Comment: I'm not sure, but the functions are being encapsulated. I think so.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want?

```js
function append() {
    var ol = document.getElementById("ol1");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = (`LIST ITEM <input class="input"><button class="add" onclick="add(this)">ADD</button><button class="remove" onclick="remove(this)">REMOVE</button><ol></ol>`);
    ol.append(li)
}

function add(e) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = (`LIST ITEM <input class="input"><button class="add" onclick="add(this)">ADD</button><button class="remove" onclick="remove(this)">REMOVE</button><ol></ol>`);
    e.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("ol")[0].appendChild(li);
}

function remove(e) {
    e.parentElement.parentElement.removeChild(e.parentElement);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <button id="btn1" onclick="append()">Append</button>
    <ol id="ol1">
    </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 'closest' in the add method, you can simply find the parent and append in that.

EG :  tgt.parentNode().appendchild(childLi)